# Why is my Objects.values() returning false when my array of Objects has a matching value?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I have a variable, `memberId` which has a unique value. I'm trying to use `Object.values()` on my array of Objects from firebase ,to return true for the unique firebase ids in my array. Here is a console.log of my `memberArr` which is defined before this `onValue` call as `let memberArr= [];`

```js
[
  {
    "-N0IZXQkPiHD9yfwi-M1": {
      "member_id": "7cCfvX0eAlPGmamCTahFSu4p2xl1"
    }
  },
  {
    "-N0KSFc1rg91sufbUftO": {
      "member_id": "7cCfvX0eAlPGmamCTahFSu4p2xl1"
    },
    "-N0KSRwxNp34-JhkLWDE": {
      "member_id": "ssKze4rM5ucJWY9oBaJAMY7zUG03"
    }
  },
  {
    "-N0bdv6XGGfW-HDA2heI": {
      "member_id": "Lu7cfs7stqhgXXzAUp9iA7OxYaH2"
    }
  },
  {
    "-N0bnRZKUDBULaCECPfq": {
      "member_id": "Lu7cfs7stqhgXXzAUp9iA7OxYaH2"
    }
  }
]
```

my `memberId` has the same value as those last two values for `2` and `3` where the `member_id: 'Lu7cfs..` so after this block of code:

```js
onValue(dbRef, (snapshot) => {
  const data = snapshot.val();
  for (var key in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      groupArr = data[key];
    }
  }
  snapshot.forEach((groupSnapshot) => {
    memberArr.push(groupSnapshot.child("members").val());
    let memberExists = Object.values(memberArr).includes(memberId);
    console.log(memberArr);
  });
});
```

`memberExists` should return true for the last two but it returns false for all of them.

Here is a picture of the console.log for the array:

[image]

Comment: It would be easier to debug this if you included the array as _code_ rather than an image in your question.

Comment: if `memberArr` is an Array of Objects, `Object.values(memberArr)` will return an Array of Objects ... an Array of Objects won't *include* a Number ... i.e. `Object.values([{x:1}])` is `[{x:1}]` - you may want to look into using `memberArr.find` instead

Comment: What about lodash's `countBy` (https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#countBy) ? `_.countBy(snapshot.val(), ({ member_id }) => member_id)`.

Comment: Agreed. Post is edited. Took me a bit because that's one confusing array.

Comment: @Gusta FWIW, I cut-and-pasted it into the JS console then `console.log(JSON.stringify(a, null, 2))` easy-peasy, no IDE required. Note also that this could be made an executable snippet, making testing/debugging even easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working! Basically needed to create an array of the Object.values() and do a `forEach` on each of those objects, then just do an `if statement` comparing the `obj.member_id` with my `memberId`

```
snapshot.forEach((groupSnapshot) => {
  var memberValue = (groupSnapshot.child('members').val())
  var uniqueMemberArr = (Object.values(memberValue))
      uniqueMemberArr.forEach((memberObj) => {
      if(memberObj.member_id == memberId) {
      ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to map the array to array of member ids, then count them and and filter out the ones, with more than 1 occurrence.

To get an array of all the ids:

```
const ids = memberArr
  .map(entry => Object.values(entry))
  .map(({ member_id }) => member_id);
// ids = ['7cCfvX0eAlPGmamCTahFSu4p2xl1', '7cCfvX0eAlPGmamCTahFSu4p2xl1', 'ssKze4rM5ucJWY9oBaJAMY7zUG03', 'Lu7cfs7stqhgXXzAUp9iA7OxYaH2', 'Lu7cfs7stqhgXXzAUp9iA7OxYaH2']
```

Here is a full code to get unique ids:

```
const countMap = memberArr
  .map(entry => Object.values(entry))
  .map(({ member_id }) => member_id)
  .reduce((idsCountMap, id) => {
    idsCountMap[id] = idsCountMap[id] || 0;
    idsCountMap[id]++;
    return idsCountMap;
  }, {});

const uniqueIds = Object.entries(countMap)
  .filter(([, count]) => count === 1)
  .map(([id]) => id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```js
const data = [{'-N0IZXQkPiHD9yfwi-M1': { member_id: '7cCfvX0eAlPGmamCTahFSu4p2xl1'}},{'-N0KSFc1rg91sufbUftO': {member_id: '7cCfvX0eAlPGmamCTahFSu4p2xl1'},'-N0KSRwxNp34-JhkLWDE': {member_id: 'ssKze4rM5ucJWY9oBaJAMY7zUG03'}},{'-N0bdv6XGGfW-HDA2heI': {member_id: 'Lu7cfs7stqhgXXzAUp9iA7OxYaH2'}},{'-N0bnRZKUDBULaCECPfq': {member_id: 'Lu7cfs7stqhgXXzAUp9iA7OxYaH2'}}]

const ids = data
  .map(
    o => Object
      .values(o)
      .map(o => o.member_id)
  )
  .flat()

const hasDuplicatedIds = (new Set(ids)).size !== ids.length

console.log(hasDuplicatedIds)
```